# Laptop PC switched off after plugging in USB 3 hard drive

Tags: power, laptop

I have a laptop which I built from components in 2004.  The laptop is of course really old and some of the keys on the built in keyboard are wobbly/not working so I plug in an external keyboard.  The only reason I still use it is because of some legacy accounts software I use.

Today I plugged in a new USB 3 external hard drive to perform a backup (yes ironic) and the laptop immediately switched off.  I now find that the power transformer power light flashes when I plug into the laptop.  When you disconnect the flashing stops.  I also tried a different power supply and get same flashing light symptom.  What would the flashing indicate?

What is likely to have happened?  Why would plugging in a USB drive cause this?

Is the laptop likely dead now?  Any suggestions?

EDIT

I have been able to remove the hard drive and copy the data files.  I know how to do that and am not seeking help on that.  I am just interested to know what happened to the hardware.  And interested if there is anything to do to get the laptop running again.

Comment: Perhaps the extra power required by the external hard drive is more than the laptop power supply can handle?

Comment: "flashing light symptom" tells us literally nothing unless we can see which lights are activated.

Comment: What type of external drive, self powered or small laptop type external drive? If the latter those old usb ports do not have enough power to run the external drive. Usually this does not damage anything as there are supposed to be over current protections, but it may have damaged something,

Comment: @Moab This ine: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00G7LQBGS?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00 yes usb powered.

Comment: You seem to have damaged something in the power distribution: if you're lucky there may be an on-board fuse which you can replace. First thing to do is to remove the internal hard drive and copy it. Then do any hardware checks with the drive disconnected to prevent damage (assuming it has not been damaged already); plug it in again only once the BIOS screen appears on power up. But it's worth trying JohnnyVegas' suggestions in his answer below before you start diagnosing the hardware.

Comment: @user619818, yes that draws too much power for that old notebook.

Comment: @Moab That sounds like the cause then, thanks.  But surprised it killed the laptop totally.

Comment: Sorry about your bad luck, whenever one of my old PC's dies I want to have a funeral for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the laptop instantly switches off - there maybe a short on the positive/negative USB power lines of the USB3 equipment. Check the USB port itself, preferably with a magnifying glass and also replace the USB3 cable from the drive to the computer. Some USB3 cables allow usb2 cables to be used so that could be used instead to test.

If the drive works fine on another computer then there is a fault on the USB port of the laptop - It is advisable to not use that port for anything else until it gets looked at.

To possibly get the laptop working again, remove the battery for 10 mins, making sure the charger is not plugged in. This sometimes resets the power protection some laptops have to guard against shorting.

Comment: Laptop no longer switches on - with or without USB drive plugged in.

Comment: Have you removed the battery as mentioned above?

Comment: Battery removal step worked - it now has life again.